# Prove $\sin(xy)/x = a$ when $(x,y) \to (0,a)$, using the epsilon-delta definition.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

$$|\sin(xy)/x  - a| \leq |\sin(xy)/x| + |a| < |y| + |a|.... $$

Then?

Comment: Is it $\sin(xy)/y$ or $\sin(xy)/x$?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. It's sin(xy)/x

Comment: Are you sure that $\sin(xy)/x < y$? That doesn't seem obvious to me

Comment: | sin(xy)/x | = | sin(xy) | / |x|.  Then | sin(xy) | < |xy|. So | sin(xy) | / |x| < |xy|/|x| = |y|

Comment: Ah, thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: $\frac {\sin (xy)}{x} = \frac {\sin (xy)}{xy} y$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {\sin (xy)}{xy} = 1$ which you can prove via the squeeze theorem if you feel the need.

Comment: I'm not understanding the hold on this question. The question (after the edits) is well-defined. Indeed, $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,a)$ is well-defined; there is a sequence $\{(x_l,y_l)\}$; $l=1,2,\ldots$ such that for each $\delta>0$ there is an $n$ such that $|x_{n'}| $ $+|a-y_{n'}| \leq \delta$ for all $n' \ge n$. Thus the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $\frac{\sin x_ny_n}{y_n}$ is indeed well-defined and is the same for any such sequence $\{(x_l,y_l)\}$; $l=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: In fact, I even provided a solution. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  $\frac{\partial \sin(xy)}{\partial x}$ $=y\cos(xy)$, which is $y$ at $x=0$. So for any fixed $y$, the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ around $x=0$ is $yx + o(x)$.

Finish via L Hopital's rule for $(x,a) \rightarrow (0,a)$. Then conclude that this implies $\sin(xy)/x \rightarrow a$ when $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,a)$. [Let $(x_n,y_n)$ be a sequence whose limit point is $(0,a)$. Use L' Hopital to conclude that for each $\epsilon'$, there is a $\delta'$ s.t. inequality $|\frac{\sin(x_ny_n)}{x_n} - y_n| \leq \epsilon'$ holds as long as both $x_n$ and $y_n$ satisfy $|x_n| \leq \delta'$ and $|y_n-a| \leq \delta'$, and that there is an $l$ s.t. $|x_n| \leq \delta'$ and $|y_n-a| \leq \delta'$ for all $n \ge l$. Furthermore, one can conclude WLOG that $\delta' \le \epsilon'$.

Then use this to conclude that, given $\epsilon$, set $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and use the above to conclude that there exists an $l$ s.t for all $n \ge l$, the inequality $|\frac{\sin(x_ny_n)}{x_n} - a| \leq \delta'+\epsilon' \le 2\epsilon' = \epsilon$ holds if $n$ is at least $l$. Then use this to conclude $\frac{\sin(xy)}{x} \rightarrow a$ when $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,a)$.]

Comment: The first paragraph should say "The Taylor series of $\sin(xy)$ around $x=0$ (and $y$ fixed) is $yx+o(x)$.